# Filter For Fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net-core, filter, fluentvalidation

I tried to create a filter for my fluent validations but I could not send the error messages to my page. I can not see the error messages when filter runs. Is there any way to do it?

```
public class FluentValidationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IValidator<AboutMe> _validator;

    public FluentValidationFilter(IMapper mapper, IValidator<AboutMe> validator)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
       
        var value  = context.ActionArguments.Values.FirstOrDefault();
        if (value is AboutMeAddVM || value is AboutMeUpdateVM)
        {
            var mappedValue = _mapper.Map<AboutMe>(value);
            var result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(mappedValue);
            if(result.IsValid)
            {
                await next.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    context.ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                }
                
                context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AboutMeAddWithAllChildren", "AboutMe", new { Area = "Admin" });
                return;
            }
        }

        await next.Invoke();

    }
}
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. FluentValidation already have good integration with ASP.NET Core. Here's [documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html) on how to enable it. You do lose the async support on automatic approach, but in 99% cases you really don't need it or you shouldn't do it in input validation layer.